# Smooth Div Scroll "move" public method hack to work properly with endless scrolling

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am using smooth-div-scroll for my page.
I have already added an extra function to center the scrollbar with a selected element on the screen - so if I click on any element, the whole slide moves to center that element - with the move method -

but i would also like to use continuos endless scrolling, so the first element can be slided in the center as well  (if there is no endless scroll, the first element is at 0 and can not move right as there is no element to the left of it)

the limitation is in the orig code, but I would like to find a way to overcome it!

http://smoothdivscroll.com/publicMethods.html#move

> *An important thing to think about here is that if you use move on a scroller that is set to loop endlessly it will not do the element
>   swapping that usually happens when you scroll endlessly. So if you try
>   to move 4000 pixles in a 2000 pixel wide scroller it will go to the
>   rightmost element and stop there. I haven't heard of anyone who has
>   experienced any problems with this, but if you try using it and it
>   doesn't move as far as you've expected, this might be the cause.*

---

I am using this code now.

```
//on click on any element in scroll area 
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
var offset = $('#' + clicked_id).offset();

//scroll left to center it
if (offset.left > center) { 
    target = offset.left - center; 
    $("div#content").smoothDivScroll("move",  target );
} ;

//fix the element in the center of the screen (0px move)

if (offset.left == center){
   target = 0;  
   $("div#content").smoothDivScroll("move",  target );
} ;

//scroll right to center it - but it only scrolls less or equal to the width of the element - not more or arbitrary distance

if (offset.left < center) {
   target = -1*center + offset.left;
   $("div#content").smoothDivScroll("move",  target );
};
```

here is the testin version:
http://www.s12.gasparhajdu.hu/

thx. G

Comment: So is your code working? What's your question?

Comment: the problem is that the: if (offset.left < center) part not working properly, it can not scroll (move) more than the width of the element.. just try to click on any thumbnail left from the center - compared to them on the right.
I am just looking for a possible workaround :)